# Function to convert from latitude and longitude to UTM X and UTM Y coordinate in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a function that converts longitude and latitude to UTM X and UTM Y coordinates in SQL Server. When the user provides longitude and latitude, the function should convert that information to UTM X and UTM Y coordinates.

Comment: Please show us your code and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library in .NET to be called from transact sql Converts WGS84/UTM coordinates to Latitude and Longitude

It does just the opposite, but as it uses CoordinateSharp you can download the code and change it easily to convert from lat/long to wgs84 instead.

You can download it from github:

https://github.com/j-v-garcia/UTM2LATITUDE

```
usage:

SELECT dbo.UTM2LATITUDE(723399.51,4373328.5,'S',30) AS Latitude, dbo.UTM2LONGITUDE(723399.51,4373328.5,'S',30) AS Longitude

result: 

    39,4805657453054    -0,402592727245112

    <param name="XUTM">pos UTM X</param>
    <param name="YUTM">pos UTM Y</param>
    <param name="LatBand">Latitude band grid zone designation letter (see http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) </param>
    <param name="LongBand">Longitude band grid zone designation number (see http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) </param>
```